# PHP : Como pasar variable id

Tags: php

Resultado:

> Notice: Undefined variable: cat in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\forums.php
>   on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cat in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\forums.php
>   on line 20
>
> SELECT * FROM forums WHERE    idcategory =
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\inc\link.class.php on line 62

**index.php**

```
$obj = new DSagredo();

$categories = $obj->getCategories();

foreach ($categories as $category) 
{
    $category = $cat["idcategory"];

     echo $cat["category"]; 

    $foros = $obj->getForums($category);

}
```

**link.class.php**

```
function getForums($categoria)
{
    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE idcategory =". $categoria;

    $res = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

   /*if(isset($data)){
        return $data;
    }*/
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cambiar

```
$category = $cat["idcategory"];
```

por

```
$cat["idcategory"] = $category
```

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: Undefined variable: cat in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\forums.php
>   on line 18 Notice: Undefined variable: cat in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\forums.php on line 20

Debes declarar una variable antes de usarla.